# How to get the previous line when searching in history

Tags: bash, grep, command-history

I sometimes search in history to find a command:

```
➜ history | grep release-it
 5811  npm init release-it
 5822  release-it
 5831  npx release-it
 7350  release-it --help
```

I would like to show the 4 previous lines, so I could understand in what context I used this command. Is there a way to add context to history search to see the previous (and maybe following) lines?

Comment: This is really a question about `grep` and not about [command-history].

Comment: If you run `man grep` it'll tell you what to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `-B` ("before") option of grep:

```
history | grep -B4 release-it
```

Similar options include also `-A` ("after") and `-C` which stands for "context", it works as `-A` and `-B` combined.